# How to make tree transparent in java?

Tags: java, swing

I want help please . I want to make tree transparent . I tried to use Opaque  method `jTree1.setOpaque(false);`,but it doesn't work ,then i tried to set background to the tree .

> `jTree1.setBackground(new Color(110,110,110,110));`

it work but not working well !

[image: the image]

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] so we can test and see the same output as you